# comunication losses in encoders with can open protocol

Tags: plc, encoder, canopen

Recently adquired two encoders RM7012 from IFM with CanOpen comunitacion, I have problems with the sychronization of these, I have comunication losses, when these encoders are working both at the same time.
I tried to contact the support but I dont have any answer. I control the system with a Plc TM241CE40R from Schneider Electric.

I want to couple these encoders to my system, if there is a specialist in CanOpen comunication, contact me to talk about a Support Service.

Comment: Do the Nodes communicate ok individually?  By that I mean can you read from the registers, are there any heartbeats (if setup).  Are the Node ID's of the Nodes correct?  Are the speeds/rates correct?  Is the CAN Bus terminated correctly? These are just a few of the things to check if you can (no pun intended).

Comment: All you said it's OK. A friend told that It's a problem with the syncronization. These encoders are from other stack that the system had initially. I tried to put any value of this syncronization. There is a specific value but i dont know how to find this value

Comment: Ok I see.  Sorry, it's been a while since I looked at the SYNC objects in CAN Open.  Check the Timing Settings and COB_ID in the OD Entry.  If you have a Lawicel/PCAN device or similar see if you can use the CAN Bus viewer to see what is being transferred, etc.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.